# strange Memory Leak

Tags: android

**Edit: I think there is a logic error in the code for parsing xml so there shouldnt be any leaks if it is written properly.**

So i added my project an AsyncTask class that i wrote a while ago for quick testing purposes but it is causing memory leak errors.

I am sure it is responsible because when i removed it leak problem goes away.

Here is the heap dump file (already converted) http://www7.zippyshare.com/v/83628026/file.html

```
package com.example.xmldl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Xml;

public class Dlxml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    //adding or removing Override didnt matter just to let you know
    InputStream istream = null;
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url){

        try {
            downloadXml(url[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void downloadXml(String url) throws IOException {   
        try {
            URL mUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            istream = urlConnection.getInputStream();           
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(istream, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "resources");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {                  
                    parser.nextTag();                   
                }
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }               
            }           
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            istream.close();            
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: It would be much simplier if you'll make screenshot of dump view to not force us to setup MemAnalyzer on current PC. Thanks

Comment: @AlexN Which spesific page do you want me to take ss?

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe you are closing your inputstream :

```
private void downloadXml(String url) throws IOException {   
    try {
        URL mUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream istream = urlConnection.getInputStream();           
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(istream, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "resources");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {                  
                parser.nextTag();                   
            }
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }               
        }  
        // dont forget to close the input stream!
        istream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //error closing istream
        e.printStackTrace();        
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh sorry i close inputstream at finally. Just removed that while pasting somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In this code I can't see a possible memory leak issue. So it must be in a code included from this. Since I don't know the XmlPullParser maybe is there. Anyway the input stream should be closed at finally branch, for that you have to modify your code

```
finally {
            istream.close();            
        }
```

not good :)

```
finally {
      if(istream != null){
            istream.close();            
       }
}
```

better :)

Comment: It is why this is leak is strange there is so little code to cause a memory leak i think. But it is a full blown memory leak :/ Btw: I am sure it is this class causing memory leaks because if try to execute this from another Activity leaks sprung like hell.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases that memory leaks occurs to me in Android, it comes from Thread issues. So, I can firstly ask to you how are you calling this class (the Dlxml, that extends from AsyncTask). Make sure that you are NOT using anonymous variables, such as "new Dlxml().execute()", because Android's garbage collector can take long time to detect that a thread isn't usefull anymore (if you are using the loader in a list, it can generate a lot of leaks). I'd like to recommend you to check these two points before implementing the parallel proccessing:

- Always use static variables to instantiate loaders. This helps to prevent leaks and is, even, an Android warning annotation. Try to use static class variables on threads and handler issues;
- Take care with which thread you is calling methods that change view. If you call a method within a thread that isn't main and that changes the view, the logcat gonna throw a message about leaking. To this, make use of activity's runonuithread method;

**Important thing**: I figured out that you have used AsyncTask, and is doing a lot of things only in background. Does something of these things change the view? You can do the download on **doInBackground** and change view in **onPostExecute**.

You can also be interested in these links:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
- http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2012/01/avoiding-android-memory-leaks-part-1/

Comment: I was using a anonymous variable so i'll change that right away to see if that fixes. I am not posting anything back yet this task was posting some log messages to logcat but i removed it for readability. Can you give a code example to your first suggestion please?

Comment: Changed my code as you suggested to but it doesnt prevented it: Dlxml getXml = new Dlxml();
         getXml.execute(mUrl); //mUrl being a static variable

Comment: As posted by matheszabi, it's hard (if it really exists) to see a memory leak in this code snippet. One more thing to ask: are you using something to close your connection? I usually see these three to close a web service request:
- httpPost.abort();
- closeInputStream();
- httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
Hope that it helps in some way... :)